# Baiduspider is crawling my site even when forbidden by robots.txt, how do I prevent it?

Tags: htaccess, apache, robots.txt

My site has heavy traffic because some bot. I checked access_log, some bot Baiduspider go to my site 10-20 times per minute. I do not need Chinese traffic. I have searched and read http://www.baidu.com/search/robots_english.html

I added rule into the *robots.txt* then restarted Aache, but it doesn't work. Baiduspider still crawls my site.

```
User-agent: Baiduspider
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
```

I found their feedback page http://zhanzhang.baidu.com/feedback/index I can translate the page to my language, but I cannot translate and insert captcha.

Then I have searched and find some article: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/blocking-bad-bots-and-scrapers-with-htaccess.html But when I add it into `.htaccess`, I cannot access my site,(you do not have permission to access this site) Am i inserted in a wrong position? need a help.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider.* [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

#some custom rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^article/([^/\.]+)/?$ /article/$1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

BTW, my server is CentOS7 apache 2.4.6. I also tried "httpd.conf", but I never find any article about apache 2.4.6 `<IfModule setenvif_module>`, all the articles are `<IfModule mod_setenvif_c>`... apache 2.4.6 do cancel `order allow,deny` rule, I have no idea how  to modify and add into my `httpd.conf`.

Anyway, I just want to refuse `Baiduspider` Thanks.

Comment: Baidu is often fairly well behaved. It is possible that since Baidu is a Japanese/Chinese search engine mostly from China, that some scrapers are using the agent name and going rogue. This may be what you are seeing. Otherwise, this is something I need to look into further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try blocking specific IP addresses in your .htaccess file. You can find the ranges [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/Baiduspider_id_4086.php).

In robots.txt you can also add the following

```
User-agent: Baiduspider
User-agent: baiduspider
User-agent: Baiduspider+ 
User-agent: Baiduspider-video
User-agent: Baiduspider-image
Disallow: /
```

Also, if you use caching plugins or CDN, make sure to clear all your cache.

Comment: Only the first `User-agent: Baiduspider` should be necessary to block _all_ Baidu spiders ("a case insensitive substring match" according to the "standard" and Baidu reportedly supports the "standard"). And this is stated in the [Baidu help docs](http://help.baidu.com/question?prod_en=master&class=Baiduspider). However, it can take some days for the spider to pick up the change to `robots.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem with your rewrite rule is the `OR` flag.  That flag usually means that there is a second rewrite condition coming.  You only have one condition.

[Here is a site](https://forums.powweb.com/showthread.php?t=92476) that provides a similar rule for blocking BaiduSpider with slightly different syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```